# Bootstrap 3 text-align: center not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have read through multiple questions and I know it's as simple as adding `text-align: center`, however that's not working for me.

I have also tried to add `text-center` to my wrapper `<div>` but that did not work either.

Current result:
[image] 
(Hard to see but it's all white-space to the right.  I tried to add a black border with `style="border: 1px black;"` but nothing showed up...)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" id="dataTableSegmentedControl" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">Dashboard</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Events</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#dataTableSegmentedControl button {
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to be centered?

Comment: The buttons....

Answer (score 0):

My agenda before running into this issue was to use the Bootstrap 3 way of making buttons equal in width by using `btn-group-justified`, however as my question above states it did not work for me when trying to get these buttons centered.

My end result is reverting back to using CSS to format it correctly in the center.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="btn-group" id="dataTableSegmentedControl" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dashboard</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Events</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#dataTableSegmentedControl button {
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

**Result**
[image]

It's not my desired result because the width of the buttons is a static `400px`.  I tried `50%` but that was a lot smaller.